# How can I join table

Tags: sql, mysql

[TABLE 1]

| shop_name | whole_sales_amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20000 |
| B | 40000 |

[TABLE 2]

| shop_name | locataion | representative_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | NY | 1234 |
| A | LA | 1234 |
| B | IL | 5678 |

I want to join Table 1 & Table 2 (I know that the DB table structure is not good..)

And Plz do not use like (shop_name = A or representative_number = 1234) on where clause

[result]

| shop_name | whole_sales_amount | representative_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20000 | 1234 |
| B | 40000 | 5678 |

Comment: Share what you have tried

Comment: An answer will depend on how you want to handle shops with multiple representatives.. Let's say you had additional data in shop_name B that had a location of IA with a representative_number 9876.  How would you want to divide up the wholesale amount for shop B?  both representatives get 40,000 or should each get some portion?  Or is it not possible for a shop_name to have two different representatives?  (By table design it is; but by business function it may not be)

Comment: Ideally if a shop can't have multiple representatives, then the representative number should be on the table1 and not table2.   But I can see a case being made to support possible growth in the future; having it on table2 now; but if we do that we need to understand the rules around it now. kinda a catch 22 situation.

Comment: There is no such case as you are talking about (1st reply). @xQbert

Comment: THen provided group by extensions are enabled, Dolotboy's answer should work.  and I'd ask why representative_number is on table 2 as that seems like a bad table desgin; if cardinality between repreentative and shop is 1:1 it belongs on table 1 since the cardinality between shop and location is 1:M where representative is presently.  you could alternatively add discintct to the select and remove the group by or group by all the fields in the select if group by extensions are not enabled.  However the "right" thing to do IMO is fix the table design if it's not too late.

Answer (score 1):

So to achieve what you've been asking for you can join 2 tables via JOIN statement. In the example below I query all the required data from Table1 and used Join to include the required data from Table2.

```
    SELECT t1.shop_name, t1.whole_sales_amount, t2.representative_number
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.shop_name = t2.shop_name
    GROUP BY t1.shop_name
```

Comment: Don't post code only as answer. Explain what you have done and why

Comment: Without a group by or distinct  you'll get multiple records for shop A.  There are also other pitfalls if one don't manage the 1:M assocation between representative and shop.

Comment: hi I tried this query before, but i got multiple records for shopA Like xQbert Said.

Comment: @rime it's because you need a GROUP BY like in the answer above

Answer (score -2):

It can be done like in this SELECT Query

```
SELECT T1.shop_name, T1.whole_sales_amount, T2.representative_number 
  FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.shop_name = T2.shop_name 
GROUP BY T1.shop_name;
```

You JOIN the table T1 and the table T2 by specifying the column they have in common in the JOIN. You can "see" the JOIN ON a little bit like it's SELECT WHERE T1.shop_name = T2.shop_name

The use of GROUP BY is not necessary. I added it because based on your "result" you don't seems to want to select every unique "shop_name". But if you are using the GROUP BY and there can be multiple possibility of "representative_number" for the same "shop_name", then don't use the GROUP BY in my query

Here are the different type of JOIN, by default simply using JOIN is an INNER JOIN, so it will select only data that are in both table, if for example, in your table T2 you would have another shop_name "C", it wouldn't select it because it isn't in the table T1
[image: Here are the different type of JOIN]

Comment: While this definitly works, I Personally am not a big fan of using mySQL's extend group by in this manner unless you really understand what it's doing.  Let's say for example a single shop has different representatives, which one would be presented in the result set?  Documentation says the engine is free to chose which one it picks meaning the result could vary from run to run.  I'd rather be intentional about which one is selected somehow and avoid the group by extension mySQL uses (and by default it can be enabled or disabled depending on mySQL version)

Comment: I simply based my answer on his result table... I'll add explication in my answer so he will at least understand !

Comment: Agreed and it meets the desired result.  So no negative votes.  But we need to look beyond the direct question and think about the implications of our answer.  In this case since the table structure supports multiple representatives for a shop, how would the user want that situation handled? Random selection, ok! However, if that situation arises what sales amount should be displayed?  This solution definitly meets the expected results, provided mySQL group by extensions are enabled.

Comment: We do however lack information to make a decision about what to do when a shop has multiple representatives, or even if that situation can exist.  The table structure supports it; but business rules may prevent such a situation from arising.  But as we don't know and we don't want to make assumptions we must ask.

Comment: Right of course !

Comment: Just for reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html  this is what I mean by it's free to choose, " the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want"  This is why I avoid the group by extension it has it's places for use, but I fear this isn't one of them; but I can't know without knowing how to handle shops with multiple representatives. :P  Good conversation though  and I used random when I should have said nondeterministic; but a different discusion

Comment: Will raise an exception on recent MySQL verisions, unless in compatibility mode.

Comment: How come it will raise an exception ?

Comment: @Dolotboy like so - dbfiddle.uk/5QuG91JO

Comment: Depends if group by extensions are enabled or not. If not error